# How to display simple Google Calendar List View

Tags: json

Hey folks Im very new to Json and I have been trying to integrate a calendar list view into my website. The Goal is to create a simple list view like below from my Google Public Calendar using JSON

Event Name - Start and End Date
Event Name - Start and End Date
... (display 5 upcoming events)

Here is the URL for a GET : https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4

The problem I am having is displaying items that are nested within root elements. For example, based on the URL above I want to display each item in a row for the following child elements:

"items":
    "summary",
    "start",
    "End"

In the URL above there are 3 events (i.e. items)
Id like each one of these events to appear like below:

EAA Chapter 309 - Young Eagles Event - November 18, from 8:45am - 11:00pm 
EAA Chapter 309 Build Night - November 14, from 5:00pm - 8:00pm 
etc...

So within this example the code would need to do the following:

1. List up to 5 upcoming calendar event entries
2. List the child element named "summary" from within the parent element "items"
3. Iterate down to the Start-->dateTime child element and End-->dateTime elements
4. Convert from UTC time to standard 12hr.

Here is some code I was playing around but I have no idea what Im doing. Its using tables/rows to insert data BUT the repurposed code was using a POST to a php file that had a table in it called "Customers". I was trying to repurpose code but obviously its not working.
i.e.code example - http://eaa309.club/CalendarExample.html

Any help would be awesome!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h2>Make a table based on JSON data.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
            var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
            obj = { "Table":"Calendar", "limit":20 };
            dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    txt += "<table border='1' cellpadding='7' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>Event Summary</td><td>Event Start & End</td></tr>"
                    for (x in myObj) {
                        txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].summary + "</td>" + "<td>Start & End Date from JSON Data needs to go here</td></tr>";
                    }
                    txt += "</table>"
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                }
            };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>


    <h2>Make a List based on JSON data.</h2>
    <ul id="myList"></ul>

    <!--JQuery CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      //Jquery's ajax request
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4',
        dataType: 'json',
        async:true
      }).done(function(data){
       //once we get a successful response this callback function
       //gets fired, and "data" contains the parsed json file .

       //here we iterate over the object array
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
        //I do this to later format these timestamps
        let start = new Date(item.start.dateTime); 
        let end = new Date(item.end.dateTime);
        //set options for date.toLocaleDateString() function
        var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };
         //append data to the list.
         $('#myList').append(`
          <li>${item.summary} - ${start.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)} - ${end.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)} </li>
          `);

      });

      }).fail(function(e){
        error(e);
      });

    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "Jun", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Dicember"];
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Output should be:

EAA Chapter 309 - Young Eagles Event - November 18, 1:45 PM - November 18, 4:00 PM
EAA Chapter 309 Build Night - November 14, 10:00 PM - November 15, 1:00 AM
EAA Chapter 309 Build Night - November 14, 10:00 PM - November 15, 1:00 AM

Comment: Josel82 This actually worked perfectly. Is there any way to NOT display the month information in the "let end = new Date(item.end.dateTime) but rather only display the end time?

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the info coming back is slightly off. The output display the following:

Build Night - Nov 14, 5:00 PM
Build Night - Nov 14, 5:00 PM
Committee/Member Meeting - Nov 20, 5:00 PM
Young Eagles - Nov 18, 8:45 AM

It looks like the first two are the same. One has a status = cancelled
and one two events are missing. 11/21 and 11/28. Weird. ALso is there a way to display events in order based on the dates they occur?

Hers is the URL: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4

Comment: In regards to the date format you can replace this part and it should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the first two list items where repeated was because that's what's in the JSON data. Have a look at the raw JSON and you will see it. It's just a matter of using a filter to get rid of entities with status: "cancelled". As for the date format I think this should do it for you now, just replace this part of the code in your html file and you should be good to go.

```
 //here we iterate over the object array
 $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
   //I do this to later format these timestamps
   //set options for date.toLocaleDateString() function

   var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };

   let start = new Date(item.start.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

   let end = new Date(item.end.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

   let end_splt = end.split(',');

    //append data to the list.
    if(item.status != "cancelled"){
      $('#myList').append(`
       <li>${item.summary} - ${start} - ${end_splt[1]} </li>
       `);
    }

 });

 }).fail(function(e){
   error(e);
 });
```

Comment: Cool. I looked up online last all the Ajax Methods and found a filter similar but mine didn't work. Thanks. Last Question, Is there now a way to Order by Start Date. So that the events display in order i.e. November 14, November 18th November 20 etc....?

Comment: That would require logic to sort that list by date. See if there's a way to set the google calendar API to get you that JSON data already ordered.

Comment: Looks like orderBy as part of the URL is no longer Supported in V.3 BUT it does look like the following works when directly entered into the URL.

sortorder=ascending&singleEvent‌​s=true

Comment: oooops Spoke to soon I just added a calendar event and it placed it at the end which should not be the case.